# How to make rocket engine plume?

Tags: texturing, particles, shaders

I'd like to know how to make those high velocity flames that can be visible in this vdeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjZ9ly7c08s.

I've made flames myself but they dont look very realistic https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PhE9cAXLcVc

Should i use particle systems, planes with images on them, advanced shaders or maybe smoke simulation?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a nice computer, look into smoke simulation[image]

Although, any flames that you make in space are going to look a little bit fake, because most people have never seen flames in space

Ignoring the awful camera quality, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEom0G30Gic is the type of thing that it seems like you are trying to emulate. If you want realism, I would do a quick fire thing like you have, and then overexpose the video while the fire takes up most of the screen.
Your also missing the camera shake from the rocket, your footage is unnaturally smooth.

Comment: I dont want to use smoke simulation because that smoke rises very slowly compared to rocket exhaus that can achieve even 4,6 km/s. Im looking for  something like in this video (1:30) <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8jvGDeNYb0>    also in 3:10 you can see there is not much of a shaking while separation like in my video

Comment: @M.Sobota You can change the smoke simulation to shoot smoke at whatever rate you want by using wind, or changing the smoke simulation settings.